# How to set a start date and end date to a condename One picker

Tags: calendar, codenameone, picker

I need some help to set a start and an end date to a codenameOne picker : for example I want my picker to display just date between current date and current date+20  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't support two dates in the picker, but you can use two pickers one to represent the start time and one to represent the end time.

Comment: Actually I don't want to set two dates to the picker but to limit my picker's dates between to values !! I want to show just days between for example Monday and Friday !! user will not select two days but one !!

Comment: Since the picker component is implemented natively there are limits on its customizability. You can use a picker and another custom widget that allows you to select the range (e.g. number of hours/days).